# Nginx docker as nodejs proxy in local

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx, proxy

At the moment I am using nginx in docker to proxy my node applications

for example I add `website.dev` in my host file

and my actual nginx config is

```
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {}

http {

    server {
      listen 80;
      server_name website.dev;
      location / {
          proxy_pass    http://localnode:3000;
          proxy_set_header X-Base-Path "/";
          proxy_set_header Website-Name "test";
      }
    }
}
```

And I a starting my docker container with this command

```
docker run --name infra-nginx --add-host localnode:$(ifconfig | grep inet | grep -v inet6 | grep -v 127.0.0.1 | awk '{print $2}') -p 80:80 -d docker-registry.host.com:5000/infra-nginx:dev
```

Where

```
$(ifconfig | grep inet | grep -v inet6 | grep -v 127.0.0.1 | awk '{print $2}') is getting my local ip, not working all the time.
```

The problem is if I want to work without internet, I can't.
And when my ip change, I have to restart the container with the new ip.

I tried with this config instead

```
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {}

http {

    server {
      listen 80;
      server_name localhost;
      location / {
          return 200 'gangnam style!';
      }
    }

    server {
      listen 80;
      server_name website.dev;
      location / {
          proxy_pass    http://localhost:3000;
          proxy_set_header X-Base-Path "/";
          proxy_set_header Website-Name "test";
      }
    }
}
```

And running

```
docker run --name infra-nginx --network host -d docker-registry.host.com:5000/infra-nginx:dev
```

In this case, when I am running:

```
curl http://website.dev/
```

I have

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to website.dev port 80: Connection refused
```

The `docker ps` is giving

```
81da561dd131        ajouve/infra-nginx:dev   "nginx -g 'daemon ..."   32 minutes ago      Up 32 minutes                                                          infra-nginx
```

the `netstat -plant` is giving me

```
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1/nginx: master pro
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.1:35962        172.17.0.4:27017        ESTABLISHED -
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.1:35938        172.17.0.4:27017        ESTABLISHED -
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.1:35994        172.17.0.4:27017        ESTABLISHED -
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.1:45080        172.17.0.5:6379         ESTABLISHED -
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.1:35990        172.17.0.4:27017        ESTABLISHED -
tcp        0      0 192.168.65.2:44900      151.101.0.204:80        TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.1:45126        172.17.0.5:6379         ESTABLISHED -
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.1:36000        172.17.0.4:27017        ESTABLISHED -
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.1:35958        172.17.0.4:27017        ESTABLISHED -
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.1:59172        172.17.0.3:5672         ESTABLISHED -
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.1:35976        172.17.0.4:27017        ESTABLISHED -
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.1:59106        172.17.0.3:5672         ESTABLISHED -
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.1:35980        172.17.0.4:27017        ESTABLISHED -
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.1:35996        172.17.0.4:27017        ESTABLISHED -
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.1:58356        172.17.0.4:27017        ESTABLISHED -
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.1:35966        172.17.0.4:27017        ESTABLISHED -
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.1:45112        172.17.0.5:6379         ESTABLISHED -
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.1:35932        172.17.0.4:27017        ESTABLISHED -
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.1:58366        172.17.0.4:27017        ESTABLISHED -
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.1:35998        172.17.0.4:27017        ESTABLISHED -
tcp        0      0 192.168.65.2:41386      206.251.255.63:80       TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.1:58358        172.17.0.4:27017        ESTABLISHED -
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.1:35956        172.17.0.4:27017        ESTABLISHED -
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.1:35924        172.17.0.4:27017        ESTABLISHED -
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.1:36004        172.17.0.4:27017        ESTABLISHED -
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.1:58360        172.17.0.4:27017        ESTABLISHED -
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.1:35964        172.17.0.4:27017        ESTABLISHED -
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.1:35916        172.17.0.4:27017        ESTABLISHED -
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.1:58362        172.17.0.4:27017        ESTABLISHED -
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.1:59148        172.17.0.3:5672         ESTABLISHED -
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.1:59166        172.17.0.3:5672         ESTABLISHED -
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.1:35944        172.17.0.4:27017        ESTABLISHED -
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.1:35912        172.17.0.4:27017        ESTABLISHED -
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.1:35954        172.17.0.4:27017        ESTABLISHED -
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.1:45116        172.17.0.5:6379         ESTABLISHED -
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.1:58354        172.17.0.4:27017        ESTABLISHED -
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.1:35988        172.17.0.4:27017        ESTABLISHED -
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.1:59122        172.17.0.3:5672         ESTABLISHED -
tcp        0      0 192.168.65.2:34936      5.153.231.4:80          TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 192.168.65.2:44904      151.101.0.204:80        TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.1:59162        172.17.0.3:5672         ESTABLISHED -
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.1:59180        172.17.0.3:5672         ESTABLISHED -
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.1:45130        172.17.0.5:6379         ESTABLISHED -
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.1:59140        172.17.0.3:5672         ESTABLISHED -
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.1:36002        172.17.0.4:27017        ESTABLISHED -
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.1:35922        172.17.0.4:27017        ESTABLISHED -
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.1:35970        172.17.0.4:27017        ESTABLISHED -
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.1:58364        172.17.0.4:27017        ESTABLISHED -
tcp6       0      0 :::6379                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::15672                :::*                    LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::5672                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::27017                :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

From the docker container:

```
curl -v localhost
```

Is giving

```
* Rebuilt URL to: localhost/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying ::1...
* connect to ::1 port 80 failed: Connection refused
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.38.0
> Host: localhost
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
* Server nginx/1.10.3 is not blacklisted
< Server: nginx/1.10.3
< Date: Fri, 29 Sep 2017 08:46:10 GMT
< Content-Type: text/plain
< Content-Length: 14
< Connection: keep-alive
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
gangnam style!
```

But `curl -v website.dev` is returning

```
* Rebuilt URL to: website.dev/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to website.dev (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.38.0
> Host: website.dev
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 502 Bad Gateway
* Server nginx/1.10.3 is not blacklisted
< Server: nginx/1.10.3
< Date: Fri, 29 Sep 2017 08:46:37 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 173
< Connection: keep-alive
<
<html>
<head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.10.3</center>
</body>
</html>
* Connection #0 to host website.dev left intact
```

And `docker inspect infra-nginx`

```
[
    {
        "Id": "16941d22442a257f0874a772df935514c658ac16ec67eb3f65606b4d7c0ee62e",
        "Created": "2017-09-29T08:31:21.144827953Z",
        "Path": "nginx",
        "Args": [
            "-g",
            "daemon off;"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 2656,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2017-09-29T08:31:21.548119911Z",
            "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        "Image": "sha256:25d085baee52923e32f8d134048238fb67e71173e01f758c391119235f7fc565",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/16941d22442a257f0874a772df935514c658ac16ec67eb3f65606b4d7c0ee62e/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/16941d22442a257f0874a772df935514c658ac16ec67eb3f65606b4d7c0ee62e/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/16941d22442a257f0874a772df935514c658ac16ec67eb3f65606b4d7c0ee62e/hosts",
        "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/16941d22442a257f0874a772df935514c658ac16ec67eb3f65606b4d7c0ee62e/16941d22442a257f0874a772df935514c658ac16ec67eb3f65606b4d7c0ee62e-json.log",
        "Name": "/infra-nginx",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "aufs",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "",
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": null,
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "host",
            "PortBindings": {},
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "no",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": false,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": null,
            "CapAdd": null,
            "CapDrop": null,
            "Dns": [],
            "DnsOptions": [],
            "DnsSearch": [],
            "ExtraHosts": null,
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": null,
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 67108864,
            "Runtime": "runc",
            "ConsoleSize": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "Isolation": "",
            "CpuShares": 0,
            "Memory": 0,
            "NanoCpus": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
            "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": [],
            "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
            "DiskQuota": 0,
            "KernelMemory": 0,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 0,
            "MemorySwappiness": -1,
            "OomKillDisable": false,
            "PidsLimit": 0,
            "Ulimits": null,
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": null,
            "Name": "aufs"
        },
        "Mounts": [],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "moby",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "443/tcp": {},
                "80/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "NGINX_VERSION=1.10.3-1~jessie"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "nginx",
                "-g",
                "daemon off;"
            ],
            "ArgsEscaped": true,
            "Image": "ajouve/infra-nginx:dev",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": null,
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {}
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "175272649c9a9c5abbfde7516328bdab5cb3825e1e027eee0580eb18f7ff77cb",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {},
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/default",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "",
            "Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "",
            "IPPrefixLen": 0,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "",
            "Networks": {
                "host": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": null,
                    "NetworkID": "3e04a4c12b5a5b3f55e7b4e918dadec64806b5c926fc249e8aa3e28398a02954",
                    "EndpointID": "7de54daaa31230c9492a463792015af727e9562eaacbaa0c2d70cdc3d3b04236",
                    "Gateway": "",
                    "IPAddress": "",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 0,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` where?

Comment: With `curl http://website.dev/`, I updated the post

Comment: Add output of `docker ps` to your question

Comment: Updated, the container is running, there is no port using `network host`

Comment: Go inside the container and run `netstat -plant` and add that output also

Comment: Does `curl -v localhost` work inside the container? Also add `docker inspect infra-nginx` to the question

Comment: Let's see if I understood correctly.
You have an `app running locally  with nodejs`, you have a `docker container running nginx` and you want to access to your local `nodejs app` through your `nginx container` using a custom host name from you local machine.
Am I right?

Comment: Are you averse to using something other than nginx?

Comment: @PedroJimenez yes

Comment: @CliveMakamara I am also use to apache

Comment: Which OS this running on?

Comment: @TarunLalwani MacOS 10.12.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So when you run it using `--net host` it actually still is not on mac network as such. That is why it is not working.

From the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/#use-cases-and-workarounds)

> The Mac has a changing IP address (or none if you have no network access). From 17.06 onwards our recommendation is to connect to the special Mac-only DNS name docker.for.mac.localhost which will resolve to the internal IP address used by the host.

So you need to change your config to

```
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {}

http {

    server {
      listen 80;
      server_name localhost;
      location / {
          return 200 'gangnam style!';
      }
    }

    server {
      listen 80;
      server_name website.dev;
      location / {
          proxy_pass    http://docker.for.mac.localhost:3000;
          proxy_set_header X-Base-Path "/";
          proxy_set_header Website-Name "test";
      }
    }
}
```

And you should run the container as below

```
docker run --name infra-nginx -p 80:80 -d docker-registry.host.com:5000/infra-nginx:dev
```

Answer (score 1):

You're making it way too complex. Just EXPOSE a port like 8080 from your app container.

In nginx use:

```
listen 80;
server_name _;

location / {
   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.2:8080;
}
```

Comment: The node app is not running into a container, I can't easily access my ip from the container

Answer (score 1):

Ok I think the solution I did is simple enough.

First I have an app in nodejs running on the port 3000 on my local machine, so if I go to localhost:3000 in the browser I can see the app running.

Then I create a file called `default.conf` inside a folder in my machine `~/projects/docker/default.conf`, ***you can create that file wherever you want***. And paste this code inside the file:

```
server {
listen 80;

server_name myapp.com;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

}

Look the line `proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;` I am redirecting to my app running on my local machine.

Then I run a `nginx container` with the following command:

```
sudo docker run -d -p 80:80 --name="nginx" --net="host" -v ~/projects/docker/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro  nginx
```

The `-p 80:80` is to bind that port to the `nginx container`

The `--net="host"` is to tell the container that the network it will use is the same that the host, it means the same as my machine, with this I can forward to the `localhost:3000` from inside the container.

The `-v ~/projects/docker/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro`
 is to tell to the `nginx` that its configuration file will be the file I have in my local machine.

It means something like: You will find this `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` file in this `~/projects/docker/default.conf` location

And that's all.

If I go to my browser and type just `localhost` ***(without the port)*** it will go through the `nginx container` and will be redirected to the app running in the `localhost:3000` in my local machine

***Let me know if this helps you***